# Swift load user data for dashboard after login

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to retrieve user data once the user gets to the dashboard of my app

I have essentially this to get data:

```
class UserController: ObservableObject {

    @Published var firstName: String = ""

    func fetchUser(token: String) {
        
        /* Do url settings */

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let rData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
            let userData = [
                "id": rData.id,
                "firstName": rData.firstName,
                "lastName": rData.lastName,
                "department": rData.department,
            ]
            UserDefaults.standard.set(userData, forKey: "user")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.firstName = rData.firstName
            }
        
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

And then my view looks like this

```
struct HomeViewCollection: View {

    @Binding var isAuthenticated: Bool
    @ObservedObject var userController: UserController = UserController()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello \(userController.firstName)!")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure how can I activate fetchUser from the View.

I have tried this in the controller

```
init() {
    guard let tokenData = KeyChain.load(key: "token") else { return }
    var token = String(data: tokenData, encoding: .utf8)
    if(token != nil) {
        print("Token: \(token)")
        fetchUser(token: token!)
    }
}
```

That didn't work, and then I tried `userController.fetchUser(token: KeyChainTokenHere)` and that didn't work because it doesn't conform to the struct.

Comment: Did you make sure the `firstName` is getting set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the `token` to `HomeViewCollection` and initiating the call in `onAppear` completion block.

```
struct HomeViewCollection: View {

    var token: String
    @Binding var isAuthenticated: Bool
    @ObservedObject var userController = UserController()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello \(userController.firstName)!")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.userController.fetchUser(token: self.token)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, make sure the `firstName` property is getting set.

```
@Published var firstName: String = "" {
    didSet {
        print("firstName is set as \(firstName)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works great! I just am having trouble getting the token value from the keychain but that's a different issue, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Try debugging the issue by yourself. If you're still not able to resolve the issue add another post on SO, post the link in the comments will try to help you out.

Comment: @M4TRIX Also, if the answer helped don't forget to upvote.